# Why is it "dog eat dog"?

Tags: grammar

Why is it **dog eat dog**?

It should be: *Dog 'eats' dog*

or

*Dogs 'eat' dogs*.

Why does it sound ungrammatical?

Comment: It's like a saying, comparable to 'Good mind; good find', where grammar rules can be compromised.

Comment: [Idioms Online](https://www.idioms.online/dog-eat-dog/) has: 'The modern idiom directly contradicts an old Latin saying, canis caninam non est, meaning “a dog does not eat the flesh of a dog.” This was first recorded in English in 1543. Thomas Fuller wrote in Gnomologia, in 1732, “Dogs are hard drove when they eat dogs.” The modern idiom, which is still very popular, was in use by the early 1800’s.' Perhaps an attempt to better reflect the Latin, perhaps a non-standard aim at punchiness that has caught on.

Comment: Could have sworn that someone already asked this exact question, but I can’t find it. In any case, this question might answer this: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/24486/191178

Comment: _Very_ good spot, @Laurel.  This sort of thing is so rare (I think) that arguing from analogy might be imprecise; I take it that's the reason you haven't C-V'd.

Comment: Why CV the Q...? @EdwinAshworth For dupe? Sorry, I cannot see that back channel stuff.

Comment: @Rattler If you mean you don't hold with the policy of keeping the site from bloat, you'd better take that up on Meta. It's always been pointed out that the principle aim of ELU (and as far as I'm aware, all SE sites) is to build up a reliable, comprehensive and easily searchable database. Not reinvent the wheelbarrow innumerable times, answering every reincarnation of a question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry...I was only asking the reason for close. Not expressing an opinion...

Comment: This idiom has always struck me as strange since dogs don't eat dogs. I know idioms aren't supposed to make sense, but I don't understand its popularity. "Bird-eat-bird" would make literal sense. Metaphorically, "tiger-eat-tiger" would be more dramatic. Is there a historical reason why "dog-eat-dog" became popular?

Comment: Why is it "dog-eat-dog"?  Because cats are picky eaters.

Comment: @KenShirriff: because dogs *don't* eat dogs—*except when driven to desperation*. The expression is saying that the world is like the almost unimaginably horrible circumstances that would drive a dog to eat a dog.

Comment: @NickMatteo Exactly correct. When you say "It's a dog-eat-dog world" you are saying "It's a harsh, brutal world where everyone must look out for themselves. Even dogs will eat other dogs, that's how bad it is."

Answer (score 34):

*Dog eat dog* is not a sentence; [it's an adjective](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dog-eat-dog) (and it's usually hyphenated).

You can modify a noun with it:

> *It's a dog-eat-dog world.*

You can also use it as a predicate adjective:

> *The music business is dog-eat-dog.*

Does that still sound ungrammatical to you?

If you are still wondering about agreement within this idiomatic multi-word adjective, perhaps this entry from the *OED* -- will soothe your mind:

> **dog**, *n.1*  **PHRASES P1.** Proverbs and proverbial sayings.
>   **c.**  [after Latin *canis caninam non est* ( Varro De *Lingua Latina* vii. 32)] ***dog does not eat dog*** and variants: people of
>   the same calling, origin, etc., do not deliberately harm one another;
>   conversely ***(let) dog eat dog*** (cf. *dog-eat-dog n.* and *adj.* at
>   Compounds 3a).

There the third-person imperative *let* accounts for the bare infinitive *eat*. Here are a couple of examples offered at this entry:

> <sub>1835   W. G. SIMMS *Partisan* I. v. 59:   He cannot escape
>   Travis..who knows the swamp as well as himself. They're both from
>   Goose Creek, and so let dog eat dog.</sub>
>
> <sub>917   G. L. MORRILL *Devil in Mexico* 328:   Do nothing, let dog
>   eat dog—this is the policy of non-interference.</sub>

Here's another example. An elliptical *will* accounts for the bare infinitive *eat* here:

> <sub>1789   *Times* 19 June 3/1:   As it is an established fact, that
>   sharper will not rob sharper, nor dog eat dog.</sub>

<sub>Definition and examples source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Did that bare infinitive *eat* inform the adjectival version? I don't know for sure, but if you still have doubts, then the "It's an idiom!" excuse will have to do.

Comment: But why dog-eat-dog and not dogs-eat-dogs? 'According to the Oxford English Dictionary ... man-bites-dog is an adjective of U.S. origin' [[Everything2 thread](https://everything2.com/title/Man+Bites+Dog)] This shows that saying it is an adjective explains little about the reason for the internal form.

Comment: dog-eat-dog pre-existed the American newspaper headline origin of man-bites-dog. But that is really irrelevant here.

Comment: +1 I hadn't even thought  of attacking the question from this angle...

Comment: Additionally, adjectives are commonly (but not always) phrased both in the singular and in a generalized form. This means that when a verb is used as part of an adjectival phrase, it's construction is often in the infinitive. Which is why, idiom aside, it wouldn't typically be *dogs-eating-dogs*, for instance. But perhaps the most specific answer is that *dog-eat-dog* is an idiom. So, it's simply what we've come to use.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I answered this based on the OP's apparent attempt to make a sentence (note the use of cap and period) out of a multi-word adjective (and an idiomatic one at that). But I have updated my answer to address the possible etymology for internal form of the idiom.

Comment: So the answer is "because it is originally 'let dog eat dog'", right?

Comment: It now answers the question, if not definitively, very eruditely and with welcome modality; and I've adjusted my voting.

Comment: Also, it's common to use the singular form when talking about food, eg "She eats chicken. In France, they eat horse". Etc.

Comment: @Brian Indeed, but I was talking about the food words, "chicken" & "horse", not the subjects or verbs of those sentences. You can say "She eats chickens", but it sounds a little odd.